# MS Excel: how to sum one column based on criteria for other columns

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vba

Running into a bit of an problem in that I can't find any function that will let me add multiple criteria to a formula to filter on.  In SQL I would put what I'm looking for in the where clause, but I can't seem to replicate that type of functionality in Excel

Columns:

```
A       B       C          D
-------------------------------
Jim     1000    Open       Jan

Bill    1200    Won        Feb

Suzy    1500    Complete   Mar

Jane    2000    Complete   Feb
```

I'm looking for a Formula that will let me say:

---

Sum values in Column B if Column C contains 'Open' or 'Complete' *and if* Column D contains 'Jan' and 'Feb'

---

Ideally I'd like to be able to even add a 3rd or a 4th column (in Columns E & F) that I could further filter the results.  Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question to me. It's more to do with formulas/filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Sum-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-e610ae0f-4d27-480c-9119-eb644f1e847e) together with a normal `SUM`:

What you wanted:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B1:B6, C1:C6,{"Open", "Complete"},D1:D6,{"Jan", "Feb"}))
```

The way this works is as follows:

`SUMIF([summing range], [range 1], [condition 1], [range 2], [condition 2], ..)`

Where

- `[summing range]` is the range to sum over
- `[range 1]` is the range of the first filter
- `[condition 1]` is the condition of the first filter
- `[range 2]` is the range of the second filter
- `[condition 2]` is the condition of the second filter
- etc.

We then need to use `SUM()` because `SUMIFS` will output an array (due to the multiple string conditions).

See the result below:

[image]